# Field translation works randomly

Tags: 7, entities, i18n-l10n

I have a 3 language website and translated bunch of field labels, the thing is that it works just for some of them not all of them. I created the forms with [Entity form](http://drupal.org/project/entityform) module and even when I check the translation for other languages it's there, it just doesn't show the proper translation and keep showing the default language instead.

Any ideas what may have caused it?

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest i18n -dev because i18n 1.8 had numerous bugs in i18n_field.

Comment: it worked, but still have problem with translating field's options such as radio buttons and checkboxes, the translation is there, still not showing it. plus leave an answer so I can check it as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module used for translating fields (title, help text, description, allowed values) is i18n_field.

Internationalization 1.8 shipped with a broken i18n_field module, so in many cases nothing would get translated.

The first issue that fixed most of the failures was
[[7.x-1.8 regression] Field translation fails in numerous situations](https://drupal.org/node/1904368)
It has now been committed and is a part of the latest -dev release.

Contrib field types such as commerce_price might need the following patch:
[Extend support for contrib field types](https://drupal.org/node/2015749)

With those patches applied I had no problem with translating any part of a field.
For translating allowed values (radio or select fields), my process was this:
1) Go to manage fields, click edit next to my list(text) field.
2) Click the Translate tab on the next page. 
3) In the table, find my language and click "translate".
4) I can translate the values under the "Field settings" vertical tab.

Also keep in mind that when showing one of those values on a rendered entity, you need to use the "Default translated" formatter (set under "Manage Display").

Comment: Thanks Bojan, but I still can't translate label options  with the exact same process you mentioned.

Comment: I suggest opening an issue in the Internationalization issue queue, and provide exact steps and screenshots detailing where it fails. Post the link here, and I will respond there.